# What's the name for words people say when they don't know what to say and need a moment to think?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm not sure how to explain this in English, since I haven't seen this exact phenomenon used by English-speakers, so I'm looking for an efficient way to explain the phenomenon in English.

The closest equivalent to what I mean would be the "uh" I've seen in American English. An example would be a quote used as the name of a research article I've recently found: “I'm Not Sure I Can Handle the Kids, Especially, the, uh, You Know Special Ed Kids”.

In some other cultures, instead of "uh", it's more acceptable to actually say a word or a short phrase that's either literally meaningless or has a meaning but adds nothing to the conversation, but is instead used as a pause for speaker to collect his thoughts or to process newly gained information without actually making a break in speaking, like for example the "you know" from the quote I posted.

So I'm looking for a short phrase or a word that can be used to refer to the above-described words or short phrases.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you might be looking for *filler*.

> In linguistics, a [filler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)) is a sound or word that is spoken in conversation by one participant to signal to others a pause to think without giving the impression of having finished speaking. [...] Different languages have different characteristic filler sounds; in English, the most common filler sounds are uh /ʌ/, er /ɜː/, and um /ʌm/. Among the youths, the fillers "like", "y'know", "I mean", "so", "actually", "basically", and "right" are among the more prevalent.

Comment: That seems to be the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, but I have a feeling there are better names for this, like _pauses, breaks_, etc. _Filler_ might not be the most "common" fit. The comments in [this post](http://blog.dictionary.com/filler-linguistics/) suggest _vocalized pauses_ and _hemming and hawing_. Let's see what others say.

Comment: "uh" and similar are called _interjections_ in most dictionaries, but @AndrejaKo is looking for a specific term established by usage, and I don't think there is one. However, [**caesura**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/caesura?s=t) from prosody might be pressed into service.

Answer (score 3):

> Fillers

is the general term for additional words used to create an effect.

A wonderful example of the usage of "fillers" is the show [*Just A Minute*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_a_Minute) on BBC Radio4, where contestants must speak on a subject for 60 seconds

> "without hesitation, repetition or deviation"

In your particular case, you are referring to

> [hesitation fillers](http://englishharmony.com/hesitation/)

which are used to gain time while formulating what to say, usually in response to an answer.